# C# Cannot convert type 'System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItem' to 'my app.Users' class

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, listviewitem

I have a C# WinForms program accessing SQL server and querying data from it. I have two main classes: `Users` which contains the datatypes for the users that can log into the app, and `Products` which contains again the datatypes for the products that can be queried. Also I have a class that holds the methods for accessing the sql server. I made a function querying the users form the sql database into a list which than I load into a `ListView lsv_MangageUsers`. I was able to create the add new user and delete method, but when I started creating the modify user method I ran into a problem. Visual Studio says:

> "Cannot convert type 'System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItem' to 'my app.Users' class".

I tried giving the selected item's value casting in `Users` class to the modify method and load into a new forms controls to allow the user to make modification on it. If I used method and function in a wrong order my apologies I am still new in C#. Any help would be appreciated.

The button's code that running the modify user method:

```
private void btn_ModifyUser_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (lsv_ManageUsers.FocusedItem.Index != -1)
    {
        UserNew userwindow = new UserNew((Users)lsv_ManageUsers.SelectedItems[0]);
        if (userwindow.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            LsvUsersRefresh();
            toolStripStatusLabel1.Text = "User successfully modified!";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It all revolves around `lsv_ManageUsers`, so please include the code where that variable is initialized. At the same time, please reduce unneccesary code, e.g. most content of `class UserNew` is irrelevant for the question. Keeping it short and to the point allows all of us to focus on the actual problem.

Comment: I deleted the rest of code which was related to saving data and had nothing to do with the exception.  The exception throws here: `(Users)lsv_ManageUsers.SelectedItems[0]`. A `ListViewItem` can not be converted to `Users` class. If you need that users object put it in `Tag` property of the item when you fill `ListView`. Then use it this way: `(Users)(lsv_ManageUsers.SelectedItems[0].Tag)`

Comment: If you use `DataGridView`, then you can simply set its `DataSource` to `List<User>` and when you want to get a user from a row, `DataBoundItem` is the data bound item behind the row.

Comment: I tried this way when I initialise my ListView:
                ListViewItem item = (Users)lsv_ManageUsers.SelectedItems[0];
                Users foo = (Users)item.Tag; 
But it still gives the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The item referenced by `lsv_ManageUsers.SelectedItems[0]` is a ListViewItem, it is not one of your `Users` items, and you can't just cast from one to another because they are completely different things.

If you want the world to work in this way then each `ListViewItem` has a `Tag` property that you are free to use for whatever purpose you feel like.  Suggest adding the `Users` item to this property when you add the `ListViewItem` to the list, and then you can dereference it within your click handler.

Comment: How should I set the ListViewItem Tag property properly? I set with this: –`Users something  = (Users)lsv_ManageUsers.SelectedItems[0].Tag;` and referenced as @Reza Aghaei said in the comments bellow in my button click handler: `(Users)lsv_ManageUsers.SelectedItems[0].Tag;` It builds successfully but gives no object in my modify variable.

Comment: When you create the ListViewItem, which you must be doing for it to appear in the list, you need to set the Tag property of the item that you've created to reference the thing that you want it to reference

Comment: Finally managed to solve the problem with your instructions. Thank you!